# p-adic Banach space and complete tensor product

Tags: p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers, non-archimedean-fields

Let $p$ be a prime and $\mathbb{C}_{p}$ the completion of the algebraic closure of the $p$-adic number field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Let $M$ be a $\mathbb{Q}_p$-Banach space.

We denote by $M\mathbin{\widehat{\otimes}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}}\mathbb{C}_{p}$ the complete tensor product over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Is the natural map $M\rightarrow M\mathbin{\widehat{\otimes}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}}\mathbb{C}_{p}$ an isometry ?

Comment: What is the complete tensor product?

Comment: TeX notes: I think that the hat in a completed tensor product is usually placed only over $\otimes$, not the ground ring.  But, either way, it needs a `\mathbin` for spacing: see, e.g., $M \widehat\otimes \mathbb C_p$ `M \widehat\otimes \mathbb C_p` vs. $M \mathbin{\widehat\otimes} \mathbb C_p$ `M \mathbin{\widehat\otimes} \mathbb C_p`.  I edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  The complete tensor product is the one defined in §2.1.7 of "Non Archimedean Analysis" (S. Bosch, U. Guntzer, R. Remmert).

Comment: By Schneider, Nonarchimedean Functional Analysis, Coro 17.5 on page 106, the map is a homeomorphism on its image. Maybe studying the proof of Prop 17.4 and Coro 17.5 will help shed some light on your question?